# Show Description on Title Hover in Gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a custom list with Title and Description.

I wish to display the list view as a gallery with only the Title in it. On hover over the title, it should display the description field covering the gallery item.

I plan to implement this with list view formatting. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using JSON view formatting. Below is basic JSON sample which will help you to get started with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 53,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        },
        "customCardProps": {
          "formatter": {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "[$Description]",
            "style": {
              "padding": "20px"
            }
          },
          "openOnEvent": "hover",
          "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
          "isBeakVisible": true,
          "beakStyle": {
            "backgroundColor": "white"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

Comment: Is there a way to display the description card inside the title div container rather than a bubble? I was still able to hide the break indicator.

Comment: That will be difficult a bit. It will break when there is large description & title container is of small size. Yes, if you want you can hide the beak using JSON styling.

Comment: I was able to bring the description inside the container. But this only gets highlighted when hovered over the title. How can I make this display over card hover. 
`"txtContent": "[$Title]",
                                "customCardProps": {
                                    "formatter": {
                                        "elmType": "div",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "elmType": "div",
                                                "children": []`,

Comment: Not sure how can I post the full JSON code. So posted a chunk of it.

Comment: I am adding the customCardProp to the title. Can I add that to the full card?

Comment: Edit your original question & add current JSON you are using, then I will try some tricks at my end & see if it works.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Hi @Ashish, any update on this thread? Can you accept it as answer if it helped you?